# serialVersionUID in the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin generated code

Tags: serialversionuid, swagger-codegen

I'm using swagger-codegen-2.1.6 and successfully generated serialized model classes through swagger-codegen-maven-plugin using serializableModel configOptions. However, I don't see the serialVersionUID added to the classes, neither I can find any documentation to include it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been considered as a enhancement by swagger team , issue #3345, milestone  swagger-codgen v2.2.2.